# Shorten Minimum Range for Kinect or Asus

Tags: computer-vision, kinect, openkinect

I am planning on using a device such as the Microsoft Kinect or an Asus Xtion Pro for 3D imaging purposes and they are great on all specs except for the minimum range.  Is there anyway to make the range shorter, either through software modifications, or is there any similar hardware with a closer minimum range?

The only option I have found is this:  http://nyko.com/products/product-detail/?name=Zoom which adds an element of distortion though does reduce the minimum depth by up to 40%.

Comment: What minimum spec are you expecting (or experiencing)?

Comment: And also, what is your target range?

Comment: I am trying to see between 1 feet and 10 feet.  Right now I am getting right around 1.6 feet

Comment: I don't think you can do it. But you can get a bit closer with the Kinect for Windows which has Near Mode compared to the regular XBoX Kinect.

Comment: Kinect for Windows (not Xbox) has the near mode, in that mode Kinect can "see" at 40cm of distance. I found a compative here http://autoponics.org/?p=160

Comment: @EdgarT that link is to Kinect/XTion. I don't see a comparison of K4W v. Xbox Kinect.